# How does an Iterator work on a LinkedList?

Tags: java

I'm quite new to programming, and I'm currently learning Java, in particular, I'm now dealing with LinkedList and Iterators. I was trying to print the values of the objects the LinkedList is pointing to, and I used the following code:

```
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Iterator;
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    LinkedList<String> list= new LinkedList<>();
    list.add("Florence");
    list.add("Paris");
    list.add("Berlin");
    
    printList(list);
    }
    
    
    public static void printList(LinkedList<String> list){
        Iterator<String> i= list.iterator();
        while(i.hasNext()){
            System.out.println("Now visiting: "+ i.next());
            
        }
        
    }
}
```

In fact, when I run the program all the items are printed, but I'm afraid I don't quite understand the logic.
 This is how I get it: when the *printList* method is called, the Iterator starts from the 0th element, which has a next element, 0th element is printed and the iterator goes to the 1st element. Now it prints the 1st element and goes to the 2nd, and now I expect *i.hasNext()* to return false, causing the cycle to break.
 Clearly this is not what happens since the 2nd element is printed, so I was wondering if someone could explain me the actual process involved.
Thank you in advance for your answers,
Have a nice day,
Andrea. 
 
edit: thanks for the feedback, I understand why I do need the i.next() to iterate over the elements. Actually I don't get why when I get to the last element (and I suppose the .hasNext to return false) the value is printed anyway.

Comment: The documentation should clear things up.. "A ListIterator has no current element; its cursor position always lies between the element that would be returned by a call to previous() and the element that would be returned by a call to next().".

Comment: Thank you Voo, this perfectly clarifies the problem!